# Change currency precision in Magento 2 Product detail page

Tags: magento2

how to change the currency's precision?

want to change the precision from 2 decimal places to 3 in plp and pdp .

changed or extend function format() in module-directory\Model\PriceCurrency.php

it effect for list and cart page but in product detail page still it shows 2 decimal place

how to fix this issue

Answer (score 2):

Not recommended, but fix it this issue.
See vendor\magento\module-catalog\view\base\web\js\price-utils.js

See line 38

Change `var precision = isNaN(format.requiredPrecision = Math.abs(format.requiredPrecision)) ? 2 : format.requiredPrecision,`
to

```
var precision = you_presigion,
```